# How to get he value of <asp:checkbox>

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, model-view-controller

I am trying to get the value of the below code. i am using VB at server side.

```
<asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Release Payment">
        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="table-head-p"></HeaderStyle>
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="grid-cd"></ItemStyle>
        <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:checkbox id="chkRelease" CssClass="select-check" runat="server"></asp:checkbox>
        </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. Checkboxes have no value, code has no value either. Are you trying to see whether the checkbox on the selected row is checked?

Comment: I am also assuming that you're using a datagrid but please add more mark-up and edit your question for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value using the IsChecked property:

```
bool didYouCheckTheBox = myCheckbox.IsChecked;  // returns true or false
```

The default value is false, unless you specifically set the checkbox to be checked in the markup or in the code behind.

Comment: checkboxes have no value. they have a state. they are either checked or unchecked